# Double Quotes are not correct in my Database records ” instead of "

Tags: mysql, double-quotes

I have a client's website that has thousands of MySQL records that have text links and HTML.

My problem is some of the links in the Database are using this `”` instead of `"`

Now when I search the database to try and find just the `”` it is treating `”` and `"` as if they are exactly the same.

This creates a nightmare trying to update thousands of these, anyone have any suggestions on a solution to update them all?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Demoroniser](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/demoroniser/). It fixes bad microsoft formatting, such as "smart quotes." Just run it with the contents of the database as your input, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, my client pays writers to write blog post so they likely use MS Word or something that's causing the issue

Answer (score 2):

I normally `mysqldump` the database, do a find and replace on the SQL file (in your preferred text editor) and restore the database (after testing it locally!!!).

Works a treat when you've got to shift a wordpress site from one domain to another as all of you links to your media are absolute URIs to your old address!